# How can I get an msi (VS Setup Project) to install a Windows component?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, msmq, setup-project

I have a Visual Studio Setup project that creates a Message Queue (MSMQ). It fails on computers where the Message Queue component is not installed.

Is it possible to get the installer to enable/add this Windows Component?

Answer (score 3):

I think that you would be so much better off just providing sample instructions. There are so many variables that the machine administrator that may need to be taken in to account. We just specify that  MSMQ needs to be installed and the installer reports if it is missing.

Comment: We do the same thing with our app.  Plus, if something goes wrong, do you want to be responsible for a breaking change to a user computer?

Comment: This is the reason - we can't do it. Our customers generally all have IT admins who'd castrate us if we did anything to affect their lock down policies. We have to work with them as they know there computers 100s times better that we ever could discover.